# Processing - Changing orientation of the camera and fixed text position

Tags: camera, orientation, processing

I would like to be able to change the camera orientation while displaying text at a fixed position. The camera angle should change as a function of the mouse position on the window.

Let's consider this example:

```
int sizeX = 600;
int sizeY = 600;

void setup()
{
  size(sizeX, sizeY, P3D);
}

void draw()
{
  background(204);

  stroke(0, 0, 0);
  //camera(mouseX, height/2.0, (height/2.0) / tan(PI*30.0 / 180.0), width/2.0, height/2.0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  place();
  stroke(0);
  displayInfos();
}

void displayInfos()
{
  stroke(0, 200, 200);
  line (0,20,sizeX,20); // monitor bar
  fill(0);
  textSize(10);
  text ("TEXT 1:", sizeX*0.05,sizeY*0.1-20);
  textSize(12);
  text ("TEXT 2", sizeX*0.7,sizeY*0.95);
}

void place()
{
  pushMatrix();
  translate(sizeX/2, sizeY/2, 0); 
  noFill();
  rotateX(-PI/6);
  rotateY(PI/3);
  box(150);   
  popMatrix();
}
```

The `displayInfos()` function draws a line a writes some text in a fixed position while the `place()` function draws a box in the middle of the screen.

[image]

If I uncomment the camera command in the `draw()` function the whole scene rotates. I would like the text and the bar to be fixed on the screen and the box to rotate based on the mouse position.

How can achieve this in Processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the call to the camera() function right after the pushMatrix() function:

```
void place()
{
  pushMatrix();
  camera(mouseX, height/2.0, (height/2.0) / tan(PI*30.0 / 180.0), width/2.0, height/2.0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  translate(sizeX/2, sizeY/2, 0); 
  noFill();
  rotateX(-PI/6);
  rotateY(PI/3);
  box(150);   
  popMatrix();
}
```

Calling pushMatrix() basically says "remember the current rotation and translation", then you can do whatever rotations and translations you want, draw some stuff, then call popMatrix() which basically says "go back to those other settings I told you to remember".

So now you're remembering (pushing) the default rotation, doing the rotation and translation (via the camera function), drawing the box, then going back to the default rotation via the popMatrix() function. Then when you draw the text, it's using the default rotation and translation again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Clean and concise answer